# PHP - Extract numbers and enclose them into <span>

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract the numbers from some strings and enclose them into ... It's something like this:

```
$string1 = "Up to 3 bedrooms";
$string2 = "With 2 and 3 (wathever)";
echo myMagicFunction($string1); // Up to <span>3</span> bedrooms.
echo myMagicFunction($string2); // With <span>2</span> and <span>3</span> (wathever).
```

I think I could use preg_replace, but i dont know how...

Tks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function myMagicFunction($str)
{
    return preg_replace('/\d+/', '<span>$0</span>', $str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\d+` to match successive digits, `$0` to put match in the replacement string

```
function myMagicFunction($string) {
    return preg_replace('/\d+/', '<span>$0</span>', $string);
}
```

EDIT: Exactly the same function got posted 1 minute before. I guess there is a definite answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$tok = strtok($string1, ' ');

$result = "";
while ($tok !== false) {
 if ( is_numeric($tok) )
    $result .= "<span>" . $tok . "</span>";
 else
    $result .= $tok;
 $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
}
```